# Add directory to path for sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

I know creating a .bashrc and adding

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/asco/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools
PATH=$PATH:/home/asco/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools
```

will add those directories to my path. 
How do I do the same so the programs in those directories will be available with sudo?
I tried the same as su in /root, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO easiest way is to add those lines to `/root/.bashrc`

Alternately, you can add `/home/asco/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools` and `/home/asco/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools` to `/etc/environment`

Last, you could, as root, move the sdk directory to a central location on root's path, such as `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: as of latest Ubuntu LTS, adding things to PATH in `/etc/environment` doesn't do it for commands ran under sudo.